# How do I mathematically express this?

Tags: probability, statistics

Probability of getting selected  from a pool of 5 applicants but the available slots are 10 (more than the applicants).

I know that it should not go beyond 100%, how do I do this?

Im just coming from the fact that let's say 2 applicants and 6 slots, therefore 33% of getting "chosen."

Comment: do you mean probability of placing an applicant on a specific slot?

Comment: @NikosM. Yes howver how do you express it in a function/mathematically that I have 100% probability because I only have 5 applicants but there are 10 slots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you ask what is the probability that a candidate out of 5 is chosen when you choose all 5, since you have plenty of available slots.

An intuitive way of defining the probability of an event is the ratio between the number of favourable cases and the number of possible cases. For instance, if you had 3 applicants and 1 slot, then you would have 1 favourable case and three possible ones, and the probability would be $\frac{1}{3}$.

In your situation, all the possible cases are favourable, therefore the probability of getting selected is $1$.

Comment: So for my case, 5 applicants, 10 slots. 5/10? Isn't that 50% when it should be 100% that these 5 are getting in? Sorry I completely understand the concept but I just cant translate this into a function which I need for something else.

Comment: Let's keep in mind that we're counting the **outcomes**: we have 5 applicants and we choose all of them, because we have even more than 5 spots to fill. Hence, in all the possible outcomes, the 5 applicants are chosen, meaning that all the possible outcomes are favourable. Therefore our ratio between number of favourable outcomes and number of possible ourtcomes is 1, or 100% if you prefer.